# When is a g-dimensional subspace of $H^1(S; \mathbb{C})$ the $H^{1,0}$ of a complex structure on $S$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, teichmueller-theory

Given a closed surface $S$ of genus $g \geq 1$ there are lots of choices of complex structure, and each one singles out a subspace of the surface's first cohomology group with complex coefficients corresponding to the classes of 1-forms which are holomorphic on that Riemann surface.  Given an "appropriate" subspace, when does it correspond to the $H^{1,0}$ for some choice of complex structure?

To be more precise, let $\mathcal{T}(S)$ be the Teichmüller space of $S$, whose elements are pairs equivalence classes of pairs $(X, f)$ where $X$ is a Riemann surface and $f : S \to X$ is a diffeomorphism, with $(X, f) \sim (Y, g)$ if there is a holomorphic $\Phi : X \to Y$ such that $g^{-1}\Phi f$ is isotopic to $\mathrm{id}_S$.  Using the marking $f$, we can pull $H^{1,0}(X)$ back to a complex $g$-dimensional subspace of $H^1(S; \mathbb{C})$.  It is **not** the case that every $g$-dimensional $V \subseteq H^1(S; \mathbb{C})$ corresponds to some $H^{1,0}(X)$ for some choice of complex structure on $S$.  For example, the theorems of Haupt and Kapovich (independently, see [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/fla2019.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekapovich/EPR/fla2019.pdf)) state that a character $\chi : H_1(S; \mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{C}$ will correspond to a holomorphic 1-form on *some* choice of complex structure if two conditions are satisfied.

If I had a $g$-dimensional $V \subseteq H^1(S; \mathbb{C})$ where each element satisfied the Haupt-Kapovich conditions, is it true this subspace corresponds to some $H^{1,0}(X)$?  The issue that comes to mind is if $\chi, \kappa \in V$ they correspond to holomorphic 1-forms on Riemann surfaces, but is there a reason they should be holomorphic 1-forms on *the same* Riemann surface?

Comment: Surely not, simply for dimension reasons. There are interesting related questions on realizing pairs and triples of characters as periods, discussed in this MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9006/representations-of-surface-groups-via-holomorphic-connections. It seems that there is a paper of Bogomolov-Soloviev-Yotov about this, but I do not know if it is available.